# Proving $\{ x\in \mathbb R \ |\ \exists n \in \mathbb N \ 2^nx \in \mathbb Z\} \subset \mathbb Q$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{ x\in \mathbb R \ |\ \exists n \in \mathbb N \ 2^nx \in \mathbb Z\}$ Show $A\subset \mathbb Q$.

To me this seems so obvious that x would need to be a rational with a denominator that can be expressed as $2^n$ to be in the integers but I'm not sure what the trick is for the proof.
So far I have

Let $a \in A$ then we have that $a\in \mathbb R$ and $\exists n\in \mathbb N$ such that $2^na\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Put $2^na=b$ with $b\in Z$ then $a=...$

Comment: you are on the right track. Since $2^na \in \mathbb{Z}$, thus $2^na=k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.....

Answer (score 0):

So any such $x\in A$ will lead to some $n\in{\bf{N}}$ such that $2^{n}x\in{\bf{Z}}$, then some $m\in{\bf{Z}}$ is such that $2^{n}x=m$, so $x=\dfrac{m}{2^{n}}$, exactly one of the rational number.

Answer (score 0):

Every $x \in A$ must be of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ for whole numbers $m$ and $n$, so $x\in Q$. So $A \subseteq Q$

Moreover, there are many rational numbers not in $A$, e.g. $x = \frac{1}{3} \not \in A$ since $\frac{2^n}{3}$ is not a whole number.

Hence $A$ is a strict subset of $Q$, i.e. $A \subset Q$